# Java refactoring tool/eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse

I'd like to modify obfuscated program but replace only modyfied classes. I need to change names of variables etc. to understand the code, but when I do this the program will not work because the names in modified and unmodified classes are different.

Is there anything (eclipse plugin would be great) which allows me to change names but reverses the changes before compiling? (eg I see NoiseGenerator.class but the real name is apo.class)

Comment: Isn't for anything wrong or illegal, right?

Comment: Minecraft modding is not illegal unless I distribute unmodified classes too. This is why I need the tool. I can't change the names - they are used in unmodded classes, but i need to change them temporary to understand code and the tool to change them back.

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse you can (right mouse) Refactor > Rename. On the tooltip select "Open Rename Dialog", enter New Name, check "update references", click Next. You get a dialog with the changes to be performed. There you can select the ones you want the rename be applied to.

Needless to say that you'll have to decide which new names you want.

Furthermore, eclipse keeps an internal history of your code. You can restore any previous point when you're done. In any case you should consider to backup your code first and perhaps to use a version control system.

Comment: I can't use it. The names must stay same in compiled code but I need them to change in source code and the plugin to do it.